# PHP - query is not executing if called through function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am making a script that checks if the credentials a user gives are valid (the user exists). I am a php noob and i can't understand why my script doesn't work.

So can you explain me why if i do this it works:

```
<?php
// include database constants
include_once("../config/config.php");                   

// create db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt-> store_result();
printf(" Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
$stmt -> close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

But if i do this it doesn't?

```
<?php
// include database constants
include_once("../config/config.php");                   

// create db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


function check () {
  printf("check called\n"); //debug
  $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=? AND password=?");
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> store_result();
  printf(" Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
  $stmt -> close();
}
check();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The output in the first version is -> Number of rows: 1 (or 0 depending the input)

But in the second version the output is simply -> check called. Why this part

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt-> store_result();
printf(" Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
$stmt -> close();
```

is not executed when used as a function

Comment: The db variable is not global, it needs to be a parameter

Comment: Jari,Cristian Bitoi  thank you both for your answers. I flipped a coin in order to decide whose answer i accept as i consider them equally good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you not pass to function `check ()` variable `$email` and `$password`. If you not use global keyword in your function, the variable will be visible only outside the function scope.

If you want, you could use global keyword to use it variable from global scope in your function:

```
function check () {

  global $email; // from gloabl scope
  global $password; // from global scope
  global $mysqli; // from global scope

  printf("check called\n"); //debug
  $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=? AND password=?");
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> store_result();

  printf(" Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

  $stmt -> close();
}
```

See more **[here](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.variables.scope.php)** about variable scope and global keyword.

Comment: I thought they were global. I didn't know they had to be explicitly declared as global. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because, the `$mysqli` variable is not accessible inside `check()`, thats why.

This is how it supposed to work - just pass parameters to the function:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

function check (MySQLi $mysqli, $email, $password) {
  // Your stuff
}

check($mysqli, $email, $password);
```